# Understanding NiFpga_MergeStatus() function with a hard-coded value as a parameter

Tags: c++

I am picking up on someone else's code (which works and is currently being used in hardware applications). The given code is implemented in Qt since we need to produce an application, and creates an application which allows the user to set certain parameters using a gui while the code handles transferring this command through a NI PXI to the FPGAs etc.

On my way of understanding this code, I found a function call to `NiFpga_MergeStatus()` shown in the code below. The parameter passed as the first argument has been hardcoded and set to `NiFpga_Status_Success` (which if you follow the path is a `static const NiFpga_Status` type set to the the value `0`.

When looking at the `NiFpga_MergeStatus()` function implementation, I believe with this value being hardcoded, we will never get to the second if statement and our return value will be the Invalid Parameter value.

Why would somebody want to implement such code? Especially since the second parameter is sent it seems to have had some thought put into this. Am I wrong in analyzing that with harcoding the status parameter before it's passed as an argument we will always execute the first if statement? Let me know if I should provide more details. The header file is provided by Ni (`NiFpga.h`).
Thank you

NiFpga description of this function's purpose:

```cpp
 * Conditionally sets the status to a new value. The previous status is
 * preserved unless the new status is more of an error, which means that
 * warnings and errors overwrite successes, and errors overwrite warnings. New
 * errors do not overwrite older errors, and new warnings do not overwrite
 * older warnings.
 *
 * @param status status to conditionally set
 * @param newStatus new status value that may be set
 * @return the resulting status

static NiFpga_Inline NiFpga_Status NiFpga_MergeStatus(                                           
    NiFpga_Status* const status,                                               
    const NiFpga_Status  newStatus)
{
    if (!status) //
        return NiFpga_Status_InvalidParameter;
    if(NiFpga_IsNotError(*status)
    &&  (*status == NiFpga_Status_Success || NiFpga_IsError(newStatus)))
        *status = newStatus;
    return *status;
}
```

Comment: Although the project has used Qt the code that samples does not use anything of Qt so the tag is unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status is a pointer parameter. In first if statement (`if (!status)`) it is only checking if the pointer is actually pointing to something in memory or not. So in your case it always evaluates to false and `return NiFpga_Status_InvalidParameter;` never gets called.

But second if statement is doing the job of comparing actual value (note the asterisk *) of status (`*status`) with  `NiFpga_Status_Success`.

Comment: But status is set to 0, so (!status) should be a nonzero number and thus the first if statement should be evaluated, is my logic faulty there?

Comment: You may be correct on that. Could you please post declaration of `NiFpga_Status` and the line which calls `NiFpga_MergeStatus` function?

Comment: /**
     * Represents the resulting status of a function call through its 
    return value.
     * 0 is success, negative values are errors, and positive values 
    are warnings.
     */
 typedef int32_t NiFpga_Status;
Sorry, how do I make an inline code? I tried ticks from the help section but it still comes out as plain text.

Comment: @TJ178 You may use ` character at the beginning and end of your code

Comment: In the meantime, I guess in the function which is calling `NiFpga_MergeStatus` function you should have something like `NiFpga_Status myStatus = NiFpga_Status_Success;` and then function is called like `NiFpga_MergeStatus(&myStatus, /*whatever other param is*/)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (The second parameter is actually another completely not understandable function call for me, but from the documentation the second argument basically returns either an error (negative value) or a value that it reads from an indicator from a session pointer (positive value).)
The code block where this Merge function is called has a main point of returning that indicator positive value of the second argument, so my guess is that the status argument that is initially set to `NiFpga_Status_Success` is just a placeholder which is replaced by either an error or the desired value.

Comment: cnt'd, I just don't understand how we will actually get to executing the second if statement which actually replaces the initially set status to the new value it obtained by analyzing the second argument because to me, it will always be true for `if(!status)` and thus will never actually get replaced.

Comment: @TJ178 You confirmed that status is passed to the function using address location of another variable (`&myStatus`).  Therefore in `NiFpga_MergeStatus` function, status is actually pointing to address of `myStatus` variable in memory and as a result it is not zero. Value of status (`*status`) which respectively is value of myStatus is zero then. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Oh! Yes! Let me just try to reiterate below to make sure I actually got it, but thank you so much for your patience. I see it now! I appreciate your help very much!

Once the `MergeStatus(&myStatus, ...)` function is called, evaluating `if(!myStatus)` is not the same as evaluating `if(!*myStatus))`. `if(!myStatus)` sees only the address that myStatus is pointing to, not the value, and thus `if(!myStatus)` evaluates to zero. In the next if statement we are comparing the actual value that myStatus is pointing to because it is used as `if (*myStatus...)`.